# Does a variable with the value of $("#my_input").val() take up less space than one with $("#my_input")?

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm looking into ways to optimise jQuery/Javascript code and improve code style.

I've been referring to professional blogs and authoritative sources like:

https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html

https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors

But also had a few "I wonder if..." moments and was playing around with defining selectors at the beginning of large functions.

For example, rather than:

```
var myFunction_A() {
// lots of code

var my_input = $("#my_input").val();

if (my_input === "x") {
// do something
}

}
```

Do this:

```
var myFunction_B() {
var $my_input = $("#my_input");
// lots of code

if ($my_input.val() === "x") {
// do something
}

}
```

I wondered though:

- Would the variable `$my_input` be larger in size than `my_input`?
- Would using `$my_input` be slower than using `my_input`?

It's my first time using the site, but I ran a [jsPerf test](https://jsperf.com/selectors-first-or-val-only/1), and it seems that defining a selector first is quicker (~6-10%), but am still not sure about variable size.

It seems intuitive that `$my_input = $("#my_input")` would be larger, but I thought perhaps 'behind the scenes' `my_input = $("#my_input").val()` might still be 'holding' a reference to the full element value.

**HTML**

```
<input id="#something1"> 
<input id="#something2">
<input id="#something3">
<input id="#something4">
<input id="#something5">
```

**jQuery**

*Test 01*

```
var $something_01 = $("#something1");
var $something_02 = $("#something2");
var $something_03 = $("#something3");
var $something_04 = $("#something4");
var $something_05 = $("#something5");

console.log($something_01.val());
console.log($something_02.val());
console.log($something_03.val());
console.log($something_04.val());
console.log($something_05.val());
```

*Test 02*

```
console.log($("#something1").val());
console.log($("#something2").val());
console.log($("#something3").val());
console.log($("#something4").val());
console.log($("#something5").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable size is different, in one case it's an object with large data set. with lots of references. `$my_input`
and in the other, it's a simple object in some cases, and a native variable in others. much much smaller. `my_input`

however, the usage which you demonstrated, has little affect on the performance, since the same functions (cpu calls) were made.

in your case, you could have also, simply remove the variable and compare directly.

```
var myFunction_B() {

if ($("#my_input").val() === "x") {
// do something
}

}
```